# Working out what page a blog post is shown on

Tags: php, sql, blogs

Normally can figure out logical things like this but cant think of how to do what i want.

So, I have different blogs, that can contain many posts.

I am making a notification system and want to link the user to the page that a specified blog post is on.

Example:

- A user leaves a comment on a blog post. The blog post ID is 10.
- The user gets a notification which I want to link to the particular blog and page number that the blog post features on.
- The blog has 20 updates in total with 4 shown on each page.

So out of 5 pages, how do i determine which page that blog post is shown on?

The blog posts are saved in a table and all the posts are in a random order as they are added all at different times.

I hope this makes sense, cant get my head around it.

Craig.

Comment: Are you not just linking directly to the blog post? Why are you concerned with finding it in a paginated list of blog entries?

Comment: There are 4 blog posts on each page. I could just link to a page that showed one blog post... but would rather the user is directed to the page that the blog post is on. So out of 4 pages, the blog post is on page 3. I want to direct them to that page. But not sure how to work that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust that your posts all have uninterrupted, sequential ID's then it will be on page `ceil($post_id / $posts_per_page);` or `ceil(10 / 4);` or `3`.

However, you probably can't trust the ID's to be perfectly sequential (after deletes, or maybe unpublished posts, etc) so you will have to get your result array, and then figure it out:

```
$results = array(
    // Page 1
    array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'First Post'),
    array('id' => 29, 'title' => 'Foo'),
    array('id' => 53, 'title' => 'Bar'),
    array('id' => 5, 'title' => '...'),
    // Page 2
    array('id' => 87, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 9, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 147, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 18, 'title' => '...'),
    // Page 3
    array('id' => 19, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 10, 'title' => 'The One We Are Looking For!'),
    array('id' => 201, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 112, 'title' => '...'),
    // Page 4
    array('id' => 13, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 214, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 15, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 146, 'title' => '...'),
    // Page 5
    array('id' => 25, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 27, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 30, 'title' => '...'),
    array('id' => 32, 'title' => 'Last Post For Now'),
);

$post_per_page       = 4;
$target_post_id      = 10;
$results_key_we_need = false;
$page_in_results     = 1;

foreach ($results as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value['id'] == $target_post_id)
    {
        $results_key_we_need = $key + 1;
        $page_in_results = ceil($results_key_we_need / $post_per_page);
        break;
    }
}

echo $page_in_results;
```

This way, no matter how your result set is generated, you can still hunt down what page the result you want is on, using the `ceil(x/y)` function.